# Deleting a selected row via mouse click in TStringGrid using delphi

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

I'm not sure how i would capture the row selected by a **mouse click** and then press a button to delete that selected row in a stringGrid in delphi.

```
procedure DeleteRow(Grid: TStringGrid; ARow: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := ARow to Grid.RowCount - 2 do
    Grid.Rows[i].Assign(Grid.Rows[i + 1]);
  Grid.RowCount := Grid.RowCount - 1;
end;

procedure TManageUsersForm.RemoveRowButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Recordposition : integer;
begin
  UserStringGrid.Options := UserStringGrid.Options + [goEditing];
  UserStringGrid.Options := UserStringGrid.Options + [goRowSelect];
end;
```

So the first procedure is for deleting a row and the second makes sure when a user clicks a cell the whole row is highlighted not just that 1 cell.

**The mouse click is the most important part!**!

Thank You :)

Comment: Well, there's the `OnClick` event

Comment: oh well im not sure how to use this :(

Comment: It's interesting that you stress the mouse. Do you know that the keyboard can be used to make selections?

Comment: yeah.but i thought it would be easier for the user to use a mouse click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mouse click is not the most important part. Users can select a row either by keyboard or mouse, it doesn't matter, you'd just want to delete the current row. In the case of a mouse click, or otherwise, you can get the current row by `Row`.

```
procedure DeleteCurrentRow(Grid: TStringGrid);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Grid.Row to Grid.RowCount - 2 do
    Grid.Rows[i].Assign(Grid.Rows[i + 1]);
  Grid.RowCount := Grid.RowCount - 1;
end;
```

Call it like;

```
DeleteCurrentRow(UserStringGrid);
```

Answer (score 2):

I imagine the problem you might be having is to work out which grid row the user has clicked on.  One way is:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  StringGrid : TStringGrid;
  Row : Integer;
  GridRect : TGridRect;
begin
  // The Sender argument to StringGrid1Click is actually the StringGrid itself,
  // and the following "as" cast lets you assign it to the StringGrid local variable
  // in a "type-safe" way, and access its properties and methods via the temporary variable
  StringGrid := Sender as TStringGrid;

  // Now we can retrieve the use selection
  GridRect := StringGrid.Selection;

  // and hence the related GridRect
  // btw, the value returned for Row automatically takes account of
  // the number of FixedRows, if any, of the grid
  Row := GridRect.Top;

  Caption := IntToStr(Row);
  { ...}
end;
```

See the OLH about TGridRect.

Hopefully the above will be sufficient to get you going - you've obvious already got most of the way yourself.  Or, you could try the method suggested in the other answer, which is a little more "direct" but this way might be a bit more instructive as a "how to".  Your choice ...